Problem invoking OpenVMS Language-Sensitive Editor
I am attempting to invoke the OpenVMS Language-Sensitive Editor in order to create a Fortran program. DECset for OpenVMS Guide to Language-Sensitive Editor states the command is:
$ LSEDIT [/qualifiers] [file-spec]

I tried a simple unqualified command:
$  LSEDIT x.for
%DCL-W-IVVERB, unrecognized command verb - check validity and spelling
 \LSEDIT\

I checked that there is a license:
$ show license lse/full

Active licenses on node V922:

LSE
        Producer: VSI
        Units: 6
        Version: 0.0
        Release Date: (none)
        Termination Date: 30-APR-2025
        Per Core License
        Activity: 0  
        X86_64

What is my next step?
$show system
OpenVMS V9.2-2  on node V922   10-AUG-2024 20:09:11.04   Uptime  0 00:32:56

Using the Community Package:

The Community Package is a vmdk file of an OpenVMS system disk with
OpenVMS, compilers and development tools installed and licensed that
you can use to create a virtual machine running OpenVMS on x86.


The license is installed, but is the product? I'd probably try something like $ dir Sys$SysRoot:[*...]LSEDIT*.* to see if there are obvious product files.

The immediate problem is that the command LSEDIT is not defined in your command tables. The most likely cause is LSEDIT has not been installed even if you have a licence for it.
Going from ancient memory, you might be able to define LSEDIT as a foreign command
LS==$sys$system:LSEDIT
or do
RUN SYS$SYSTEM:LSEDIT
to see if it has been installed.
